# Login form application using C# and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I wrote an application in C# using Entity Framework 5.0, now I have username and password in database, I want to login with that data to my application but I can't.

This is where I'm stuck:

```
private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    Database1Entities connect = new Database1Entities();
    Users users = new Users();

    if (users.username == usernameTextBox.Text && users.password == passwordTextBox.Text)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to first find one record by username, then you compare if the password is correct. And you would usually do this with hashed passwords, but i'd worry about that later.

Comment: But ***PLEASE*** don't store your password in clear text in your database table !!!! This is a ***HUGE*** security NO-GO !

Comment: Also: Entity Framework is ***NOT*** a database - it's a data access library. The database might be SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL - whatever - but EF is not a database

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, im still learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
    using var db = new Database1Entities();
    var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == usernameTextBox.Text).FirstOrDefault();

    if (user != null && user.password == passwordTextBox.Text)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```